# Window Batch, code will work when pasted into command prompt, but not when run as a batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am having an issue with a section of code designed to count the number of times a string appears in a text file. It will work perfectly when pasted into command prompt, but when run as a .bat file it immediately closes before completing (It doesn't perform the pause before the last echo command).

```
set Logpath="C:\Users\bob\Desktop\project\a.txt"
set StringToLookFor="asdf"

set NUM=0
for /F %N in ('find /C %StringToLookFor% ^< %Logpath%') do set NUM=%N
pause
echo %NUM%
```

Comment: Since you say "immediately closes" i assume you are double clicking the .bat file. You can try to run it on the command prompt, or adding `cmd /k` to the top of the bat file to keep the terminal open after you dbl click it (or do the link+do not close option). This will show you the error... it might be failing *before* the pause.

Comment: When I do that it returns the expected result with no error.

Comment:  i confess i am not a proficient windows user. I only know a few tricks, and I am happy on linux where things are a little more predictable. But happy that works now. Good lucky figuring out why though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding a second % before N apparently fixed it.

```
set Logpath="C:\Users\bob\Desktop\project\a.txt"
set StringToLookFor="asdf"

set NUM=0
for /F %%N in ('find /C %StringToLookFor% ^< %Logpath%') do set NUM=%%N
pause
echo %NUM%
```

Comment: This is the solution. Use `%` when in CMD and `%%` when writing a batch file.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Why does Windows require this, what's the logic behind it?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `Timeout` command.

Use it like This: `timeout {your time in seconds} >nul`

`>nul` is used for silencing the console for showing. It's not neccesary for the code to work.

Don't use the {} brackets when typing in the code. For Example, I'll use it for 10 seconds:

`timeout 10 >nul` , not `timeout {10} >nul`.

If you put it in correctly, It should have a time limit until the next line.
In total, you should have a waiting time to spare.

Comment: Why do you repeat an answer that has been already deleted?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1213059)